# ffmpeg: changing framerate breaks mp3 audio in mp4

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

**What I'm going to do**: I'd like to join a set of (46) images and a (1.8 second) mp3 file to a mp4 file.

**What works**: When I use `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4` (more or less the statement from https://superuser.com/a/852252 ), then ffmpeg creates the mp4 file and everything is fine: there is audio and video in a player like VLC.

**What does not work**: When I use a framerate of 30 (instead of 25), VLC shows video only, but does not play audio.

**Question**: What can I do to get it to work with framerate 30 (even when there are not enough images to cover the whole mp3 duration)?

**Additional information**:

When I copy images so that there are 60 of them (2 seconds at framerate 30), then VLC plays the mp4 with audio and video.

When I add the `-shortest` option like this `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -c:a copy -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4` then VLC plays only audio and not video.

This is how the output for framerate 30 looks like. It is nearly the same for framerate 25 (but "30" instead of "25" and some other durations/times/ids).

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, image2, from 'img%09d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:00:01.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgr24, 480x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
[mp3 @ 0x5557d053efc0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Duration: 00:00:01.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x5557d0536e00] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1280x1280, q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
[mp4 @ 0x5557d054f640] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=   47 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=     259kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate=1446.3kbits/s speed=0.454x    
video:253kB audio:4kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.892266%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.97  size:186405
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] frame P:16    Avg QP:19.79  size:  2808
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] frame B:30    Avg QP:23.61  size:   889
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] consecutive B-frames:  4.3%  0.0% 95.7%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] mb I  I16..4:  3.0% 82.4% 14.6%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.3%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.1%  1.2%  1.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 10.5%  0.2%  0.1%  direct: 0.2%  skip:89.0%  L0:22.9% L1:75.6% BI: 1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] 8x8 transform intra:81.7% inter:83.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 90.3% 94.8% 82.0% inter: 0.8% 1.6% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] i16 v,h,dc,p:  0% 46%  4% 50%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 18% 10%  8%  9%  8% 10% 10% 14%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 14%  7%  8% 15% 11% 10%  9% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 20% 15% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] ref P L0: 86.6%  3.5%  7.2%  2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] ref B L0: 79.9% 19.4%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5557d0550340] kb/s:1317.43
```

Comment: Does it work if you reencode with the default aac codec?

Comment: When I do this `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -c:a aac audio.aac` and then `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.aac -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4` - the result is the same: VLC shows video, but does not play audio. At framerate 25 it's working fine with aac as it is with mp3.

Comment: I meant `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.aac -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Comment: ... and conversion in a single statement `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.aac -c:v libx264 -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4` does work for framerate 25 (=when the video is longer than the audio), but not for framerate 30 (=when the audio is be longer than the video).

Comment: @kesh: it's the same result with your statement.

Comment: I also tried a wav file: `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i img%09d.bmp -i audio.wav output.mp4` works fine. Framerate = 30 shows the same problems as it does with aac and mp3.